# Professionals appear to interpret sample correlation (e.g. Karl Pearson) as if it represents linear correlation. Is it the correct interpretation?

Tags: correlation, distribution, pearsons-correlation-coefficient, interpretation

I am stressed following  the wrong interpretation. What is the correct way of understanding a correlation coefficient.

Comment: Have a look at Wikipedia (top two images on the right hand side) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient

Comment: @Peter Please give an explanation of these images

Comment: I don't understand what you ask exactly. The images simply tell you, that certain non-linear relations are not detected by the Pearson measure. So in a sense you can say that it is a linear type of measure. At least there are non-linear patterns for which Pearson finds no correlation. As a general rule, try to formulate your questions in a brief but also detailed way. Your question is not up to the standards of the forum.

Comment: The formula postulated by Karl Pearson seems to check for non-linear association. Your statement  - "certain non-linear relations are not detected by the Pearson measure" appears to affirm. Thanks !